# pointer to struct as function argument - why its value is not updated?

Tags: c++, pointers

I try to build binary tree starting from empty root pointer, but tree do not appear. However when firstly I add any leaf to tree, everything works fine. My question is, what is wrong in insert function that root pointer is not updated?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct BTree
{
    int value;
    BTree *left;
    BTree *right;
};

BTree* newLeaf(int _value)
{
    BTree *p;
    p = new BTree;
    p -> value = _value;
    p -> left = nullptr;
    p -> right = nullptr;
    return p;
}

void insert(BTree *root, int _value)
{
    if (root == nullptr)
    {
        root = newLeaf(_value);
        /*why after entering here root is still nullptr*/
        cout << "entered" << endl;
        return;
    }

    if (root -> value == _value)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (root -> value > _value)
    {
        if (root -> left == nullptr)
        {
            root -> left = newLeaf(_value);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            insert(root -> left, _value);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (root -> right == nullptr)
        {
            root -> right = newLeaf(_value);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            insert(root -> right, _value);
        }
    }
}

void print(BTree *root, int i)
{   
    if (root == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }

    cout << "Level :" << i << " " << root -> value << endl;

    print(root -> left, i + 1);
    print(root -> right, i + 1);

}

int main(){
    /*1. that works properly */ 
    /*BTree *root = newLeaf(10);*/

    /*2. that does not work */
    BTree *root = nullptr;
    insert(root, 10);

    /*rest of code*/
    insert(root,5);
    insert(root,1);
    insert(root,3);
    insert(root,12);
    insert(root,11);
    insert(root,13);

    print(root, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
root = newLeaf(_value);
```

Since `root` is passed to `insert()` by value, this accomplishes nothing useful. This sets the `root` parameter to `insert()`, but the `root` object in `main`() remains unchanged. It's a different object. That's what "passing by value" means.

You need to pass the pointer by reference:

```
void insert(BTree *&root, int _value)
```

Incidentally, having done that it should no longer be necessary to check if the `left` or the `right` child is null, before making the recursive call.